# How to use a variable with an Ether unit suffix

Tags: solidity

I have this code in my contract:

```
require(msg.value == 0.06 ether);
```

But I want to replace `0.06` with a variable.

So I tried this:

```
uint256 price = 0.06;
require(msg.value == price ether);
```

But this doesn't work.


So does anyone know how to combine variables with an Ether unit suffix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
uint256 price = 0.06 ether;
require(msg.value == price);
```

You can't do `uint256 price = 0.06` because `uint256` is an integer type.

You could do something like this, I suppose:

```
uint256 percentage = 6;
require(msg.value == 1 ether * percentage / 100);
```